# Image document management application issue with deprication of NPAPI support by Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, npapi

My organization uses Gmail and Google Chrome for all communication and web-browsing needs.
We use a certain third party application for our Image Document management. From within Gmail, we usually click on links to this application to see the documents and the web browser that we use is Chrome.
The Image document mgmt application runs some Java applets and therefore needs the NPAPI plugin on the browser.
With Chrome depricating the NPAPI support, it will not be able to work as desired with the application and will not be able to display the content of the application correctly.
I dont want to use the IE Tab extension and i dont want to use an older version of chrome.
How do I circumvent this issue where I am still able to use this Image document mgmt application on the Chrome browser?

Comment: If what you want is to keep using that specific software in future versions of Chrome the only possible approach would be to contact the vendor and have them update the software to use a different, non-deprecated technology. StackOverflow can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually re-enable NPAPI for a limited time, but the Chrome team have been very strong on the point that they are not going to back down on this -- there is long term solution that will let you keep using that the way it was written. NPAPI in Chrome is going away.

Either your document management application vendor will need to update to a supported technology (see pdf.js as an example), you will need to find a different document management application to use, or (probably the cheapest option) you'll have to use another browser such as FireFox.